# Coding bat ap exam practice

Tags: java, arrays

Given an array of positive integers, return a new array of length "count" containing the first even numbers from the original array. The original array will contain at least "count" even numbers.

```
copyEvens([3, 2, 4, 5, 8], 2) → [2, 4]
copyEvens([3, 2, 4, 5, 8], 3) → [2, 4, 8]
copyEvens([6, 1, 2, 4, 5, 8], 3) → [6, 2, 4]
```

my solution

```
public int[] copyEvens(int[] nums, int count) {
    int [] a = new int[count];
    int w = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i]%2 == 0)
            a[w] = nums[i];
        w++;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Can you please explain why it doesn't work?

Comment: can you please explain why it does not work?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have braces around `if(nums[i]%2==0)` and the next **two** statements. So the `if` only applies to the first one, and you increment `w` too many times. Add braces.

```
if (nums[i] % 2 == 0) {
    a[w] = nums[i]; 
    w++;
}
```

**or** use one *compound statement* (but I would prefer the first solution)

```
if (nums[i] % 2 == 0)
    a[w++] = nums[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the earlier solution, you are incrementing "w" more times than the available space in the new array. To fix that error, you need a statement to stop incrementing once the new array is filled. `w < count` will check that your array has enough space left.

```
if (w < count && nums[i]%2 == 0) {
    a[w] = nums[i];
    w++;
}
```